# How to add tags before and after an input string

Tags: java, string, parsing

The main method receives two arguments. The second argument should be a special tag attached before and after the first argument. The result should be printed. Example:

```
String args = {"summer", "hot"};
```

Result:

> [hot]summer[/hot]

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: sorry? i did't get you

Comment: @SagarJ You haven't shown us any effort. Please add your existing code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following way.

```
String args = {"summer", "hot"};

Obj.methodName(args[0],args[1]);

public void methodName(String arg1,String arg2){
    System.out.println("["+arg2+"]"+arg1+"[/"+arg2+"]");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the following function

```
private static String functionTag(String arg1, String arg2) {
    return "["+arg2+"]"+arg1+"[/"+arg2+"]";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String arg1 = args[0],arg2 = args[1];

    System.out.println("["+arg2+"]"+arg1+"[/"+arg2+"]");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BiFunction Functional Interface which is new in Java 8, which is a functional interface that accepts 2 arguments and returns an argument. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_functional_interfaces.htm

```
import java.lang.Math; 
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

// one class needs to have a main() method
public class HelloWorld
{
  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

BiFunction<String, String, String> biFunction = (arg1, arg2) -> "Result:" + (arg1 + "[" + arg2 + "]");
    System.out.println(biFunction.apply(args[0],args[1]));
```

}
}